# Better to attach a simple function as class method or a module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, class-method

I have a simple function to prevent emails from being sent to customers when testing locally:

```
def safe_emails emails
  if Rails.env == 'production'
    emails
  else
    emails.select{|e| ['staff@example.com', 'staff2@example.com'].include?(e) }
  end
end
```

I want to share that function between mailers.  I can see two options, a module or a class method.

Option 1: Module

```
class ReportMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  include SafeEmailer

  def daily emails
    mail_to: safe_emails(emails)
  end
end
```

Option2: Class Method

```
class ReportMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def daily emails
    mail_to: SafeEmailer.safe_emails(emails)
  end
end
```

The class method is a no-no according to some due to global scope, including a module with one method doesnt seem all that attractive.  Monkey-patching ActionMailer to throw the method in there also seems like it could cause trouble (when Rails 4.3 introduces the safe_emails method or whatever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with module option even if it's a simple one function module.  Keeping a generic function that can eventually be used by multiple classes in a module makes much more sense than defining it inside a class.

If Rails 4.3 is of your concern then you can simply replace your `include MySafeEmailModule` with whatever Rails 4.3 would include this function in, as compared to find and replace all calls to `ReportMailer.daily_emails`.

Answer (score 1):

Neither – in your case, you'd need a policy object, that decides who receives email regarding the `Rails.env`. I'd keep that logic outside the `ReportMailer`.

I'd go with something like:

```
UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver if SafeEmailer.new(@user.email).safe?
```

Comment: Good point, although I'm ok with an exception being raised if I try to send an email on dev or staging to a non-dev, and I don't want to have to condition every call to mailers with the policy.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the easiest way.

Set the below configuration in your non production environments.(config/environments/.rb)

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp (default), :sendmail, :test, or :file
```

Have a look at [letter opener](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener) gem. You could have the delivery_method set as `letter_opener` and have the emails open in browser instead of actually sending them in your non production environments.

Comment: Nice gem.  In our case we need to forward test emails to higher-ups to review during development, harder to do with a webpage.